# Fuse in simpler terms

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, fuse, sshfs

I am working on `sshfs` to mount a executable to a remote cluster. One of the steps involved in this process is `modprobe fuse`. While I understand the overall purpose of `sshfs`, I am not able to understand the part `fuse` has to play. I looked up on internet about `fuse` and not able to understand clearly the purpose.

Can someone help me understand the purpose of `fuse` in simpler terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FUSE** is **F**ilesystem in **Use**rspace.

**SSHFS** is joining **SFTP** and **FUSE** together to achieve what it does. Which means it is really ineffective, slow and really not for higher workloads. But to your question:

Historically file-systems were the privilege of kernel modules, which was really painful, since writing kernel module is much more complicated than writing user-space program. FUSE is kernel module, but provides interface for user programs and if you mount file-system using `sshfs`, FUSE gets pointers to your function, that will handle system calls on that file-system (open, read, ...), which will get called when other program access the file on such filesystem.

There is really nice tutorial for understanding FUSE on [cs.nmsu.edu](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/) describing it on simple example of BBFS (Big Brother File System).